# Выделить элементы карусели

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

На сайте установлена owl-carousel 2. Карусель на всю ширину экрана с бесконечной прокруткой. Нужно сделать, чтобы первые и последние два элемента засветлялись как на картинке. Когда эти элементы попадают в сам контейнер(1170px), то засветелние убирается. Подскажите, как такое реализовать [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я вижу получилось у вас осветлить крайние изображения !

Comment: Чувак сильно абстрактно задал вопрос. используй opacity как то

Answer (score 0):

Если известно сколько елементов будет отображено, то с помощью `nth-child` добавляете `after` или `before` на активных первых и последних слайдах.

```js
$(" .js-slider ").owlCarousel({
  items: 6
});
```

```css
.x-slider {
  padding: 5rem 0;
}

.x-slider__container {
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.owl-item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.owl-item.active:nth-child(-n+2)::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.owl-item.active:nth-child(n+5)::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.green.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="x-slider">
  <div class="x-slider__container">
    <div class="b-slider js-slider">
      <div class="b-slider__slide">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150?text=1&bg=28d8b2">
      </div>
      <div class="b-slider__slide">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150?text=2&bg=8aaefc">
      </div>
      <div class="b-slider__slide">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150?text=3&bg=00bcd4">
      </div>
      <div class="b-slider__slide">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150?text=1&bg=28d8b2">
      </div>
      <div class="b-slider__slide">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150?text=2&bg=8aaefc">
      </div>
      <div class="b-slider__slide">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150?text=3&bg=00bcd4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```